# Craft Commerce 2 - get order data for plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2

I want to write a plugin which writes all the order data into a CSV file.
Unfortunately the documentation for Commerce 2 isn't quite complete yet so I have difficulties to find out how to do the following with a plugin (so I need to use PHP and not Twig).

1. Get an order by ID.
2. Get ordered items.
3. Get the addresses for the order.

Every help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$order = \craft\commerce\elements\Order::find()->id($id)->one();

if($order)
{
  foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $item) {
   // $item->description
   // $item->qty
  }

  $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
  $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
}
```